# (Numpy or PyTorch) Sum array elements for given bins

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I would like this problem to be solved using PyTorch tensors. If there is no efficient solution in torch, then feel free to suggest a numpy solution.

Let `a` be a 1-dimensional tensor (or numpy array), and `bin_indices` be a tensor (np array) of integers between 0 and `n` excluded. I want to compute the array `bins` that at position `i` contains the sum of elements of `a[bins_indices == i]`.

```py
n = 3

a = [1, 4, 3, -2, 5]  # Values

bins_indices = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]  # Correspondent bin indices

bins = [10, 3, -2]  # bins[0] = 1 + 4 + 5 etc. bins has 3 elements since n=3
```

If you can provide also a way of making this work for batches I would be immensely grateful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-line Numpy solution I could think of:

```
bins = [np.sum(a[np.argwhere(bins_indices == i).flatten()]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way but here is another solution:

```
>>> bins = torch.unique(bins_indices)
>>> vfunc = np.vectorize( lambda x: torch.sum( a[ bins_indices == x ] ) )
>>> vfunc( bins )
array([10,  3, -2])
```

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch 1.12 added a function [scatter_reduce_](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_reduce_.html) to perform exactly this kind of operations

```
import torch

n = 3
a = torch.tensor([1, 4, 3, -2, 5])  # Values
bins_indices = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 2, 0])  # Correspondent bin indices
target_bins = torch.tensor([10, 3, -2])  # bins[0] = 1 + 4 + 5 etc. bins has 3 elements since n=3

bins = torch.zeros(3, dtype=a.dtype)
bins.scatter_reduce_(dim=0, src=a, index=bins_indices, reduce="sum")
assert torch.allclose(target_bins, bins)
```